# At level 15, I can't find my martial artist armor

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I've been playing as the martial artist and until level 15 and I have the tussler equipment and I went to port Liaffan and there is no martial artist armour so I looked up where I could find how to make the armor so I was wondering if someone can help me with this. For instance, is there a certain place that I'm supposed to go where they sell it or where do I find the materials to make the armor?